# PHPExcel 1.8 VLOOKUP "#N/A"

Tags: phpexcel, vlookup

I have my excel sheet and I need to print one cell that contain VLOOKUP to the screen in HTML table. I have the following code:

```
$test = $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('test')->toArray(null,true,false,true);
$cell = $test[1][B];
echo $cell;
```

Result is always: #N/A

Im using excel 2013, xlsx and xlsm extensions.
If i try any other formula will work fine. Only VLOOKUP is giving error for me.
What can I do ?

Comment: There is a known error with the VLOOKUP code in PHPExcel that I'm currently trying to identify and fix

Comment: Im trying to replace VLOOKUP to INDEX MATCH, and in small list work fine, but in long list when I have 3000 rows, the calculation return timeout. I increase the time out to 120, 1000 seconds and stay long time thinking and nothing happening.

Comment: Yes, it's a complex calculation that will take longer to execute on a longer range of cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if this will help possible debugging, but in my own testing before I found this thread I discovered that I have the same problem but only when returning strings, I can return integers just fine.

Some of the code that I was testing with:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A150', '=VLOOKUP(100,EVENT!A30:B130,2,FALSE)');
$test = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A150')->getCalculatedValue();
echo $test;
```

In my excel sheet columns A and B are both formatted as 'General.'
Column A is a list of integers in ascending order, and column B has a mix of strings and integers. I found that when the column B cell has an integer in it, the VLOOKUP function works just fine and returns the value of the column B cell. But when the column B cell has a string in it, I also just end up with the #N/A